# Lenz's law in supercoductors: What happens if a superconducting ring approaches a bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, superconductivity

Assume that the alignment of a bar magnet passes through the center of a superconducting ring. Can we say that if we accelerate the ring toward a pole of the bar magnet applying a force $F$, the induced emf in the ring produces an opposing force exactly equal to $F$? What is the difference between using a copper ring and a superconductive one in this experiment regarding Lenz's law?

Comment: A superconductor, a magnet, and Lenz walk into a bar... wait, how does that one go?

Comment: @JonCuster Sorry, I am not following your question, please restate.

Comment: There are many jokes that start something like ‘a man walks into a bar…’ not physics at all. Sorry

Comment: @JonCuster Walking into a bar is not a good habit, though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We can think for example of the ring suddenly in free fall, from an initial zero velocity. In $t = 0$ there is a force $F = mg$ acting on it. But, as the relative velocity with respect to the magnet is zero, the field is static and there is no induced emf, and no force between them.